# s3:GetBucketLocation IAM permission for data transfer API on GCP

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

I want to use data transfer API by GCP to grab data from s3 to my GCS bucket. The S3 bucket is controlled by our client and we have zero control on it.

We learned to use this API the AWS IAM has to have these permissions:

- s3:ListBucket
- s3:GetObject
- s3:GetBucketLocation

When I asked them, they said the permission are given in prefix level and not bucket level since the bucket has data for many clients and not just us. They do not want to give any permission which might give us access to the whole bucket data and we should be limited to our prefix level.

I want to know if asking for this permission (s3:GetBucketLocation) in the prefix level will give us access to the ALL data present in the bucket? or it is just allowing the transfer API to locate the data?

I did check the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetBucketLocation.html) and the closest answer was about GetBucketLocation API which stated:

*" Returns the Region the bucket resides in. You set the bucket's Region using the LocationConstraint request parameter in a CreateBucket request. For more information, see CreateBucket."*

So it does seem it only returns the region of the bucket BUT there is no documentation to be found specific to the permission itself.

In google documentation it does say that this API is only need the region, however we need to make sure it does not open a way for us to read all the data in the bucket if that makes sense.

Please let me know if you have any knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think you need to get the bucket's region programatically. If you're interested in a specific bucket, perhaps the client could tell you the region of it?

The action-level detail is in the [SAR for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) which just says:

> Grants permission to return the Region that an Amazon S3 bucket resides in

So there's nothing about object-level (i.e. data) access granted by it.

Comment: I think the API will go for the region based on google documentation. But I am glad that you also had the same understanding as me which this permission does not seem to be object-level. Thank you for your respond :)